# When is a nail in a rotating wheel below a stated height, given its height as a displaced sinusoidal function of time?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have this question from my textbook, however I keep getting "unidentified", which is not the answer at the back.  I was wondering what I'm doing wrong.

The question is: Given that in a water wheel the height (in meters) of a nail above the surface of the water is, as a function of time (in seconds), $h(t) = -4\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1))+2.5$, during what periods of time is the nail below the water in the first 24s of the wheel rotating?

What I tried was:

first i got the period 
$$\begin{align*}
\text{period} &= 2\pi \times  4/\pi = 8\\
&-4\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)(t-1) + 2.5\\
-2.5/-4 &= \sin(\pi/4)t - \sin(\pi)\\
(\pi/4)t &= \sin^{-1}(-2.5/4 + \sin(\pi/4))\\
   &= \text{unidentified..}
\end{align*}$$

normally after that I usually get a answer find the quadrant its in 
find the actuate angle then two possible angles(then more from adding the period), however i got unidentified

the answer in the textbook is $1.86s \lt t \lt 4.14s$ ,  $9.86s \lt t \lt12.14s$,  $17.86 s\lt t\lt 20.14s$

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: my bad forgot the last sentence

Comment: It's hard to tell what function you have, because of your use of inline `/` and lack of parentheses. Does $\sin\pi/4(t-1)+2.5$ mean $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4(t-1)}\right)+2.5,\text{ or }\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1)\right)+2.5$$ or $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)(t-1)+2.5\text{ or }\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1) + 2.5\right)$$ or... ?

Comment: the 3rd one is correct

Comment: If the 3rd one is correct then the $t-1$ is outside the scope of the sine function, so the function isn't periodic, and none of your work makes sense. I suspect it's actually the 2nd of Arturo's alternatives you want.

Comment: What does "SA" in "the SA of the water" mean? Why are you trying to compute periods of the sine, if $\sin(\pi/4)$ is just a *constant* number (equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$), if, as you claim, my third formula above is correct? If my third formula above is correct, then your function is $$h(t) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(t-1) + 2.5.$$ There are no periods.

Comment: And if, as Gerry suggests, the correct formula is the second one, then you cannot go from $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1)\right)\text{ to }\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}t\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$nor to $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)t - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$The sine function is not linear, so you cannot go from $\sin(a-b)$ to $\sin(a)-\sin(b)$.

Comment: @Faraz: I've edited your question so that it corresponds to what I think your textbook must have intended, i.e., $h(t) = -4\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1)\right)+2.5$.  (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: graph of $h(t)$]

The problem requires finding the values of $t$ in the interval $(0,24)$, such that 
$$h(t) = -4\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1))+2.5 < 0.$$
Because $h$ is periodic with period $\frac{2\pi}{\frac{\pi}{4}} = 8$, the solution consists of three disjoint subintervals, which can be written as
$$(a,b)$$
$$(a+8, b+8)$$
$$(a+16, b+16)$$
The problem is then to find the values $a$ and $b$.

Now $a$ is just the least positive $t$ such that $h(t) = 0$, i.e., $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1)) = \frac{5}{8}$:

$$a = 1 + \frac{4}{\pi}\sin^{-1}(\frac{5}{8}) \approx 1.86.$$

To find $b$, notice that $h(t)$ is a sinusoid whose minima occur for $t$ such that $\frac{\pi}{4}(t-1) \in \{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k: k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, i.e., $t \in \{3 + 8k: k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$; furthermore, the least positive such $t$ (which is $3+0=3$) is just the midpoint of the subinterval $(a,b)$. Thus, $b = 3 + (3 - a) = 6 - a$.

Therefore, the required subintervals are

$$(a,6-a) \approx (1.86,4.14)$$
$$(a+8, 14-a) \approx (9.86, 12.14)$$
$$(a+16, 20-a) \approx (17.86, 20.14).$$